# How to test RxSwift Observable.interval progress

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a view model who's behaviour is controlled by an `Observable.interval`. In essence, it updates a timer label on every `next` and after a certain period, updates another value.

A trimmed example:

```
class WorkoutViewModel {
    private var _oneSecondTimer: Observable<Int> {
        return Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    }
    private let _exerciseRemainingTime: Variable<Int> = Variable(20)

    func setupBehaviour() {
        _oneSecondTimer.subscribeNext() { [unowned self] _ in
            self._exerciseRemainingTime.value -= 1
            if self._exerciseRemainingTime.value == 0 {
                self.progressToNextExercise()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have a test for this, to observe the time of event and value of `_exerciseRemainingTime`.

Is there a way how to use the `TestScheduler` to simulate virtual time in which the `_oneSecondTimer` would tick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yea, check out this simple test that has the behavior you're looking for: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/b3f4bf1/Tests/RxSwiftTests/Tests/Observable+TimeTest.swift#L496

To swap `TestScheduler` for `MainScheduler`, I would suggest you inject it as a dependency.

Also, to check on the value of `_exerciseRemainingTime`, you would need to remove `private`.  I wouldn't suggest testing the internals of your class, however. Removing `private` is a sign that you are.  Instead, if you were to inject an object whose responsibility is to do `progressToNextExercise`, then you could test that it received a call to progress to the next exercise.  You would just pass in a test version of that object during tests, like you do with `TestScheduler` for the scheduler.  That would remove the need to make `_exerciseRemainingTime` public to test it, or even know about it.

However, ignoring the visibility of `_exerciseRemainingTime` for the sake of this question's main purpose, here's what I mean about the scheduler:

#### `WorkoutViewModel.swift`

```
class WorkoutViewModel {
    private var _oneSecondTimer: Observable<Int> {
        return Observable<Int>.interval(1, scheduler: scheduler)
    }

    // not `private` anymore.  also, a computed property
    var _exerciseRemainingTime: Observable<Int> {
        return self._oneSecondTimer.map { i in
            20 - i
        }
    }

    // injected via `init`
    private let scheduler: SchedulerType

    init(scheduler: SchedulerType) {
        self.scheduler = scheduler
    }
}
```

#### `WorkoutViewModelTest.swift`

```
func testExerciseRemainingTime() {
    let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)

    let res = scheduler.start(0, subscribed: 0, disposed: 23) {
        WorkoutViewModel(scheduler: scheduler)._exerciseRemainingTime
    }

    let correct = [
        next(1, 20), // output .Next(20) at 1 second mark
        next(2, 19), // output .Next(19) at 2 second mark
        next(3, 18),
        next(4, 17),
        next(5, 16),
        next(6, 15),
        next(7, 14),
        next(8, 13),
        next(9, 12),
        next(10, 11),
        next(11, 10),
        next(12, 9),
        next(13, 8),
        next(14, 7),
        next(15, 6),
        next(16, 5),
        next(17, 4),
        next(18, 3),
        next(19, 2),
        next(20, 1),
        next(21, 0),
        next(22, -1),
    ]

    XCTAssertEqual(res.events, correct)
}
```

A couple notes to consider:

To let the test scheduler subscribe and dispose, I removed the `subscribeNext` from the view model.  I think this improves it anyway, as you should be subscribing with the view controller and only using the view model to provide you with `Observable`.  This obviates the need for the view model to have a dispose bag and manage the lifecycle of `Disposable`s.

You should really consider exposing something less "internal" than `_exerciseRemainingTime`.  Maybe something like `currentExercise: Observable<ExerciseEnum>`, which is internally based on `_exerciseRemainingTime`.  That way, your view controller can subscribe and do the simple view controller-related job of segueing into the next exercise.

Also, to simplify the test, you can inject the `20` variable into the view model so that in tests you can supply something smaller like `3` and then `correct` will only need to be a few elements long.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using an injected scheduler is what I was looking for. As for the `private _exerciseRemainingTime`, I wanted to keep the class example in the question as minimal as possible, omitting a lot (maybe too much), to focus only on the problem at hand. Thanks for the suggestions at the end, that's how I'm doing it in the full class.